# Prepare my document for submission to a paper

Tags: fonts, macros, hyperlink

I am preparing my document to be submitted to a journal via ScholarOne Manuscripts™. I have read in their online documentation [Here](http://mchelp.manuscriptcentral.com/gethelpnow/tutorials/authorfileupload.pdf), that I need to  do the following:

- Embed fonts
- Remove macros
- Remove local hyperlinks
- Embed Images and verify there are less than 100 embedded images in the file
- Remove Field Codes (placeholders in Microsoft Word for data that might     change in a document)

I have no idea what these mean and to do them. Could somebody please explain?

Comment: Is this question about LaTeX or MS Word (your last bullet point does not make that very clear)? As for LaTeX: (1) should be default, (2) is easily achievable by doing search & replace on your own macro definitions, (3) depends on their definition (didn't read it), but simply not loading hyperref may be enough, (4) is quite hard though (you could do with TikZ etc.) and (5) is irrelevant.

Comment: @TeXnician, the question is about latex. What do you mean by "replace my own macro definitions"?

Comment: My images are graphs, does it mean that I have to create them with LaTeX and not using the '\includegraphics' command?

Comment: It says it accepts pdf, so just submit your final pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your online documentation says that usually a PDF will be accepted. pdfLaTeX nowadays spills out PDFs, so all is well.

I assume that those rules apply to folks who use Word and the conversion to a PDF might be tricky. E.g. a large number of images in a Word file are a kind of challenge...